How to set up the Android custom application class with Flutter's AndroidManifest.xml configuration?
How does somebody set up the Android custom application class with Flutter's configuration? These are the instructions and you will find the data that Flutter generates below the instructions.

Setup custom application class if you don't have any.
Create a custom android.app.Application class named MyApp.

import android.app.Application
import io.maido.intercom.IntercomFlutterPlugin

class MyApp : Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    // Add this line with your keys
    IntercomFlutterPlugin.initSdk(this, appId = "appId", androidApiKey = "androidApiKey")
  }
}


Open your AndroidManifest.xml and find the application tag. In it, add an android:name attribute, and set the value to your class' name, prefixed by a dot (.).
<application android:name=".MyApp" >

My problem is that they instruct you to adjust the <application android:name="${applicationName}"> field in AndroidManifest.xml and, as you can see, I have flutter defining it as 'applicationName'. I'd prefer not to modify what seems like an important part of the AndroidManifest.xml config?
How do I know what the value of that is? And then I should name it in the class below? I'm not very experienced with the Android side!
The package in question: https://pub.dev/packages/intercom_flutter
